# docker in overlayroot environment: "invalid cross-device link"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, overlay

The docker daemon won't start inside my Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS, started with [overlayroot](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/03/10/protecting-ubuntu-root-filesystem/).

`sudo journalctl --no-hostname --no-pager -b -u docker.service`

gives me, among other things, this:

```
Feb 19 13:10:30 dockerd[1815]: Error starting daemon: rename /var/lib/docker/runtimes /var/lib/docker/runtimes-old: invalid cross-device link
```

From what I found out, this is telling me that somewhere down the line, overlay2fs is mounted inside an overlay2fs which doesn't seem to work.

Question: what do I need to do to start a Docker service inside an overlayroot environment?

Answer (score 0):

I can just bind-mount the docker directory from the overlay'd filesystem.  This works:

```bsh
mount --bind /media/root-rw/overlay/var/lib/docker /var/lib/docker
systemctl start docker
```

Unfortunately, I'm still having trouble getting this to work at startup, but that's for another question.